# How do I use a stage variable in AWS API Gateway HTTP Endpoint (http vs https)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am looking at this guide for [AWS API Gateway Stage Variables in HTTP Urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/aws-api-gateway-stage-variables-reference.html#stage-variables-in-integration-HTTP-uris). It shows all the different ways we can set up different URLs for different stages, but there doesn't seem to be a way to provide the protocol as a stage variable (http:// vs https://). If I try to add it in the endpoint in AWS API Gateway it doesn't let me.

I saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842664/handling-different-end-points-for-aws-api-gateway-stages#comment66538484_33808933) asking the same question, but for some reason there was no answer. I couldn't find anyone else trying to do the same thing anywhere else online, which is odd because I would assume a lot of people would have HTTP for their dev environment but HTTPS for their live environment.

Does anyone know how I can use different protocols (http vs https) for different stages in my API endpoint?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236152/how-to-make-aws-api-gateway-accept-http-instead-of-https. I like the `Cloudfront` answer.

Comment: I think that question is asking how to hit the AWS API Gateway using HTTP, but that's not what I am wanting to do. I am wanting to set the protocol for HTTP Endpoints (the endpoints that the API gateway will hit) with a protocol stage variable, so I can change it based on the stage. For example ${stageVariables.url} allows for a stage-based URL, but I need to define a static protocol (http/https).

Comment: You would have to have 2 API gateways (one for http and one for https) and then something in front of them that handles the routing based on the stage parameter